# Localizing $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2X, X^2)$ at $(2, X)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm working on a problem where I need to find all the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2X, X^2)$ and then computing the localization at those primes, but I'm having trouble computing the localization at $(2, X)$.

I'm aware of the identity $(R/I)_{\mathfrak{p}} \cong R_{\mathfrak{p}}/IR_{\mathfrak{p}}$. That doesn't seem to help in this case, though, as $(2X, X^2) \mathbb{Z}[X]_{(2, X)}$ doesn't obviously simplify, since $2$ isn't invertible (unlike the $(p, X)$ case for odd primes $p$, or the $(X)$ case).

Is there any other way to simplify $(\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2X, X^2))_{(2, X)}$?

Comment: As a group $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2X,X^2)= \{ a+b X | a \in \mathbb{Z}, b \in \mathbb{Z}/(2)\}$, so define the multiplication (note $(a+bX)(a-bX) = a^2$), find the elements of $(2),(X),(2)+(X)$, those not in $(2)+(X)$, and see what you get for the fractions

Comment: Thanks! After some fiddling, I've managed to convince myself that it's congruent to $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}[X]/(2X,X^2)$. I couldn't find a "slick" way to prove it, though, so I guess I just have to construct the isomorphism explicitly.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't $\mathbb Z[x]/(2x,x^2)_{(2,x)}$ just $\mathbb Z/(2)$? Because $x$ is invertible due to the localization and  $x=x^{-1}x^2=0$.

Comment: The subscript notation is unfortunately ambiguous. For a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ means inverting everything _not_ in $\mathfrak{p}$, i.e. $M_{\mathfrak{p}} = (R \setminus \mathfrak{p})^{-1} M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got around to working up a full solution to this question. The quickest way to show it is to construct $\pi \colon \mathbb{Z}[X]/(2X, X^2) \to \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}[X]/(2X, X^2)$ satisfying the universal property of localization at $(2, X)$, i.e. that $\pi$ sends elements not in $(2, X)$ to units, and is initial among such functions. Then uniqueness up to unique isomorphism automatically shows that $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}[X]/(2X, X^2) \cong (\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2X, X^2))_{(2, X)}$.